# The avatars used on stack exchange?

Tags: discussion

I like the avatars used on this site (drupal.stackexchange.com). They are "squares with some colors". Are they available and are they for free?

Answer (score 4):

Those are generated by [Gravatar](http://www.gravatar.com) based on your email address and some salt.

You can e.g. follow this link:
http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/5e17e2cc-3e32-473a-9e8c-20bdca6c138e?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG
and generate the uuid part in a unique way for each user